# Breaking a pipeline and retaining partial results

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have some pipeline in Powershell that is processing data and saving the output. 
e.g

```
$results = $data | ? {$_.Value -gt 20} | % {Invoke-EXE}
```

If I start this running, and then hit ctrl-c, $results will be null. Is there a way to stop this command, after it has started, and retain whichever results have been produced so far? 
I realize I could pipe to a file. But my pipeline is already running.

Comment: It is my command, but actually an exe (not powershell). I missed my %, if that changes things. updating my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://scriptlore.com/powershell/outvariable/

Essentially just append `-outvariable x` to your output-generating command.

In your case

```
$null = $data | ? {$_.Value -gt 20} | % {Invoke-EXE} -OutVariable results
```

Comment: I thought about this but figured it'd have the same problem; however that's not the case, it does work upon being interrupted. Good job!

Comment: I made an edit to your post because I believe that's more what he was looking for (fill the `$results` variable with whatever results have completed). Adding `-OutVariable` to `ForEach-Object` allows it to continuously collect the output as its available, in one variable.

Comment: I believe you're correct there, I am fairly new to powershell myself and the pipeline still confuses me often...

Comment: I use `-OutVariable` regularly though I admit I never knew about the `+` syntax.